# filter results on chained select boxes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have made chained select boxes i.e each select box is dependent on another select box except first select box.
when page loads user select country then state select box get populated and after state selection city select box get populated.
The chained select boxes is working fine.
**PROBLEM** 
When Page loads it has few results,on each selection result should also get filtered
EG:
 1. when page loads mix results get displayed
  2.on country selection on results related to this country should be displayed
3 after state selection results related to that country and state should get displayed.

this is the part where i'm stuck.someone helps me out
My code is
**HTML AND JQUERY**

```
    <select name="country" id="country">
    <option>select country</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * from plus2_country ORDER BY country ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($row_count > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
             echo '<option value="'.$row['country_code'].'">'.$row['country'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        '<option value="">Country not available</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
<select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="">Select country first</option>
</select>

<select name="city" id="city">
    <option value="">Select state first</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="results">
        <?php
            $query1 = "SELECT * from content ORDER BY emp_name";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($row_count > 0)
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
        ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3 photo-grid " style="float:left"> 

                        <div class="well well-sm">
                            <h4><small><?php echo $row['emp_name']; ?></small></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('#country').on('change',function(){
    var country_code = $(this).val();
    console.log(country_code);
    if(country_code){
         $('#loadingmessage').show(); 
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'dependent.php',
            data:'country_code='+country_code,
            success:function(html){
                console.log(html);
                var $state_response = $(html);
                var $result_response = $(html);
                var state_option = $state_response.filter(".state_option").html();
                console.log(state_option);
                var results = $result_response.filter("#result").html();
                console.log(results);
                $('#state').html(html);
                $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                $('#results').html(html);
                $('#loadingmessage').hide();
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#state').html('<option value="">Select country first</option>');
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
    }
});
});
```

**SERVER SIDE CODE**

```
include 'dbconfig.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["country_code"]) && !empty($_POST["country_code"])){
    $id = 1;
$code = $_POST['country_code'];
$code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$code);
$query = "SELECT * FROM plus2_state WHERE country_code = '$code' ORDER BY state ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowCount > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        echo '<option class="state_option" value="'.$row['state_id'].'">'.$row['state'].'</option>';        
    }
}else{
    echo '<option class="state_option" value="">State not available</option>';
}
$query_1 = "SELECT * from content where country_code = '$code' ORDER BY emp_name ASC";
$result_1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query_1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result_1);
$_SESSION['result'] = array();
if($row_count > 0 )
{
    while($content_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1))
    {
        unset($_SESSION['result']);
        echo "<div id='result'><div class='col-md-3 photo-grid' style = 'float:left'>
            <div class = 'well well-sm'><h4><small>".$content_rows['emp_name']."</small></h4></div></div></div>";
            $_SESSION['result'][$id] =  array('name' => $content_rows['emp_name']);
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<div class = 'result'>no results found</div>";
}
$_SESSION['country_code'] = $code ;
//print_r($_SESSION['result']);
}
```

**PS: **Should i use multiple ajax calls

**EDIT: i solved it using multiple ajax call**
**HTML And Jquery**

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option>select category</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * from category_ref_table ORDER BY category_name ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($row_count > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
             echo '<option value="'.$row['category_id'].'">'.$row['category_name'].'</option>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        '<option value="">category not available</option>';
    }
?>
</select>
<select name="department" id="department">
    <option value="">Select category first</option>
</select>

<select name="course" id="course">
    <option value="">Select dept. first</option>
</select>
<select name="subject" id="subject">
    <option value="">Select course first</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="results">
        <?php
            $query1 = "SELECT * from data_table ORDER BY title";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if($row_count > 0)
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
        ?>
                    <div class="col-md-3 photo-grid " style="float:left"> 

                        <div class="well well-sm">
                            <h4><small><?php echo $row['title']; ?></small></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#category').on('change',function(){
      var category_id = $(this).val();
      console.log(category_id);
      if(category_id){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'dependent.php',
            data:'category_id='+category_id,
            success:function(html){
                console.log(html);
                console.log(category_id);
                $('#department').html(html);
                $('#course').html('<option value="">Select department first</option>'); 
               $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'results.php',
                    data : 'category_id='+category_id,
                    success : function(response)
                    {
                        console.log(response);
                        $('.results').html(response);
                    }
               });
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#department').html('<option value="">Select category first</option>');
        $('#course').html('<option value="">Select department first</option>'); 
    }
});

$('#department').on('change',function(){
    var departmentID = $(this).val();
    console.log(departmentID);
    if(departmentID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'dependent.php',
            data:'dept_id='+departmentID,
            success:function(html){
                console.log(html);
                $('#course').html(html);
                $('#subject').html('<option value="">Select course first</option>');
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'results.php',
                    data : 'dept_id='+departmentID,
                    success : function(response)
                    {
                        console.log(response);
                        $('.results').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#course').html('<option value="">Select department first</option>'); 
    }
});

$('#course').on('change',function(){
    var courseId = $(this).val();
    console.log(courseId);
    if(courseId)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url : 'dependent.php',
            data : 'course_id='+courseId,
            success : function(html){
                console.log(html);
                $('#subject').html(html)
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'POST',
                    url : 'results.php',
                    data : 'course_id='+courseId,
                    success : function(response)
                    {
                        $(".results").html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        $('#subject').html('<option value="">Select Course first</option>'); 
    }
});
    $('#subject').on('change',function(){
    var subjectId = $(this).val();
    console.log(subjectId);
    if(subjectId)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url : 'results.php',
            data : 'subject_id='+subjectId,
            success : function(html){
                console.log(html);
                $('results').html(html);
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        $('#subject').html('<option value="">Select Course first</option>'); 
    }
   });
   });
  </script>
```

**dependent.php**

```
<?php
include 'ajax_filters/dbconfig.php';
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["category_id"]) && !empty($_POST["category_id"])){
$code = $_POST['category_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM dept_ref_table WHERE category_id = '$code' ORDER BY dept_name ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowCount > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['dept_id'].'">'.$row['dept_name'].'</option>';        
    }
  }else{
    echo '<option value="">Departments not available</option>';
   }
  }

if(isset($_POST["dept_id"]) && !empty($_POST["dept_id"])){
$dept_id = $_POST['dept_id'];
$code = $_SESSION['category_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM course_ref_table WHERE dept_id = '$dept_id'  ORDER BY course_name ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select Course</option>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['course_id'].'">'.$row['course_name'].'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">Courses not available</option>';
   }
  }
   if(isset($_POST['course_id']) && !empty($_POST['course_id']))
   {
   $course_id = $_POST['course_id'];
    $category_id = $_SESSION['category_id'];
   $dept_id = $_SESSION['dept_id'];
   $query = "SELECT * FROM subject_ref_table WHERE course_id = '$course_id'  ORDER BY subject_name ASC";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
   $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select Subject</option>';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['subject_id'].'">'.$row['subject_name'].'</option>';
    }
 }else{
    echo '<option value="">subjects not available</option>';
 }
}
?>
```

**results.php**

```
if(isset($_POST["category_id"]) && !empty($_POST["category_id"])){
    $id = 1;
    $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];
    $category_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$category_id);
    $sql = "SELECT * from data_table where category_id = '$category_id' order by title ASC ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or mysqli_error($conn);
    $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($row_count > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {   
            //unset($_SESSION['result']);
            $_SESSION['result'][$id] =  array('title' => $row['title']);
            echo "<div id='result'><div class='col-md-3 photo-grid' style = 'float:left'>
                        <div class = 'well well-sm'><h4><small>".$row['title']."</small></h4></div></div></div>";
            $_SESSION['result'][$id] =  array('title' => $row['title']);
            $id++;
        }  
    $_SESSION['category_id'] = $category_id;
    print_r($_SESSION['result']);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No results Found,we are still working on those keywords";
    }
}
    if(isset($_POST["dept_id"]) && !empty($_POST["dept_id"]))
    {
        $id = 1;
        $category_id = $_SESSION['category_id'];
        $dept_id = $_POST['dept_id'];
        $dept_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$dept_id);
        $sql = "SELECT * from data_table where category_id = '$category_id' and dept_id = '$dept_id' order by title ASC ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or mysqli_error($conn);
        $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($row_count > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<div id='result'><div class='col-md-3 photo-grid' style = 'float:left'>
                            <div class = 'well well-sm'><h4><small>".$row['title']."</small></h4></div></div></div>";
                $_SESSION['result'][$id] = array('title' => $row['title']);

            }  
        $_SESSION['dept_id'] = $dept_id;
        print_r($_SESSION['result']);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No results Found,we are still working on those keywords";
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST["course_id"]) && !empty($_POST["course_id"]))
    {
        $id = 1;
        $category_id = $_SESSION['category_id'];
        $dept_id = $_SESSION['dept_id'];
        $course_id = $_POST['course_id'];
        $course_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$course_id);
        $sql = "SELECT * from data_table where category_id = '$category_id' and dept_id ='$dept_id' and course_id = '$course_id' order by title ASC ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or mysqli_error($conn);
        $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($row_count > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<div id='result'><div class='col-md-3 photo-grid' style = 'float:left'>
                            <div class = 'well well-sm'><h4><small>".$row['title']."</small></h4></div></div></div>";
                $_SESSION['result'][$id] = array('title' => $row['title']);   
                $id++;      
            }  
        $_SESSION['course_id'] = $course_id;
        print_r($_SESSION['result']);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No results Found,we are still working on those keywords";
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST["subject_id"]) && !empty($_POST["subject_id"]))
    {
        $id = 1;
        $category_id = $_SESSION['category_id'];
        $dept_id = $_SESSION['dept_id'];
        $course_id = $_SESSION['course_id'];
        $subject_id = $_POST['subject_id'];
        $subject_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$subject_id);
        $sql = "SELECT * from data_table where category_id = '$category_id' and dept_id ='$dept_id' and course_id = '$course_id' and subject_id = '$subject_id' order by title ASC ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or mysqli_error($conn);
        $row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($row_count > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<div id='result'><div class='col-md-3 photo-grid' style = 'float:left'>
                            <div class = 'well well-sm'><h4><small>".$row['title']."</small></h4></div></div></div>";
                $_SESSION['result'][$id] = array('title' => $row[title]);
                $id++;   
            }  
        $_SESSION['course_id'] = $course_id;
        print_r($_SESSION['result']);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No results Found,we are still working on those keywords";
        }
    }
```

Comment: @GoetzPantana the link u sent is not what i want,o each selection i also want to filter the results related to that selected value,for eg: if user select `america` all results related to `america` should appear

Comment: thanx for your effort,i wanted something else,anyway i did it using multiple ajax call in single function

Comment: posted the correct answer

Comment: After code updated, looks like will be fun to impove by add selection condition and minify it.

Comment: @GoetzPantana feel free to improve the code

Comment: Where is dependent and results file code exactly ?

Comment: updated the full code

Comment: @GoetzPantana can you help me with this problem [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38697291/php-retrieve-files-under-the-directory-on-ftp-server[link]

Answer (score 0):

No need multiple ajax request instead of single one.

```
$depart = $('#department');
$course = $('#course');
$subj = $('#subject');

$res = $('.results');
$('#category,#department,#course,#subject').change(function(){
      c = 'category', d = 'department', o = 'course',
      ot = '<option value="">Select ', ct = ' first</option>';
      var s = 'subject', h = this, n = $(h).val(), k = h.id,
      el = (k==c) ? d : (k==d) ? o : s,
      jd =(k==c) ? {category_id:n} : (k==d) ? {dept_id:n} : 
      (k==o) ? {course_id:n} : {subject_id:n};
      console.log(k);
      if(k!=s){ dynoDropdowns(h, '#'+el, jd);
    } else {
        showres(h, jd);
    }
});

function seldt(e,d){
e.html(d);
}

function dynoDropdowns(el, nxtElem, dataObj){
var k = el.id, eo = ot+o+ct;
   if(k==c){ seldt($course, ot+d+ct); seldt($subj,eo);
    } else { seldt($subj,eo); }
    $.ajax({
        url:"op.php",
        type:"post",
        data:dataObj,
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){ console.log(data);
        $(nxtElem).empty()
                  .append('<option disabled>Select..</option>');
           $.each(data.ye, function(i, obj){
              $('<option>',
               { 
                   value:obj.s,
                   text:obj.d
               }
               ).appendTo(nxtElem);
           }); 
           eachres(data.pt);
        }
    });
}

function eachres(d){
$res.empty();
      $.each(d, function(i, ab){
          $('<div>',
          { 
            text:ab.nm
          }
          ).appendTo('.results');
      });
}
function showres(currElem, dataObj){
      $.ajax({
         url:"op.php",
         type:"post",
         data:dataObj,
         dataType:"json",
         success:function(data){ console.log(data);
            eachres(data.pt);
         }
      });
}
```

Also combine dependent and result file into one.

op.php

```
<?php session_start();
include'ajax_filters/dbconfig.php';
$code = $_POST['category_id']; // (int) $_POST['category_id'];
$dept_id = $_POST['dept_id'];
$course_id = $_POST['course_id'];
$subject_id = $_POST['subject_id'];

$query = ($code) ? 'SELECT*FROM dept_ref_table WHERE category_id = '$code' ORDER BY dept_name ASC' :
         (($dept_id) ? 'SELECT*FROM course_ref_table WHERE dept_id = '$dept_id' ORDER BY course_name ASC' :
         'SELECT*FROM subject_ref_table WHERE course_id = '$course_id' ORDER BY subject_name ASC');
$vs = ($code) ? 'dept_id' : (($dept_id) ? 'course_id' : 'subject_id');
$ds = ($code) ? 'dept_name' : (($dept_id) ? 'course_name' : 'subject_name');

if(isset($query) && !empty($query)){
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); // need prepared statement
$h = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ // or fetch_num
$fil[] = ( array('s' => $r[$vs], 'd' => $r[$ds]) );
}

$qt = ($code) ? 'SELECT * from data_table where category_id = '$category_id' order by title ASC':
        (($dept_id) ? 'SELECT * from data_table where category_id = '$category_id' and dept_id = '$dept_id' order by title ASC':
        (($course_id) ? 'SELECT * from data_table where category_id = '$category_id' and dept_id ='$dept_id' and course_id = '$course_id' order by title ASC':
        'SELECT * from data_table where category_id = '$category_id' and dept_id ='$dept_id' and course_id = '$course_id' and subject_id = '$subject_id' order by title ASC'));
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$qt) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); // need prepared statement

while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$jar[] = ( array('nm' => $r['title']) );
}
// json format.
echo json_encode( array('ye' => ($h>0) ? $fil : '',
                        'pt' => ($h>0) ? $jar : '') );
}
?>
```